# missing "type":feature, "geometry" from converted lon and lat data to geojson

Tags: google-bigquery, gis, geojson, apache-superset, deck.gl

i have a set of coordinates that are converted to geojson using this line of code

```
st_asgeojson(st_makeline( array_agg(st_geogpoint(locs.lon, locs.lat) order by locs.date)))as geo,
```

, which works well, also tried one row of converted coordinates on geojson.io which is displayed correctly
[image]
When i try the same line on deck.gl geojson chart in superset nothing is shown
[image]
when i compare the converted geojson data in bigquery vs the rfc 7946 standard, it seems that "type":feature, "geometry" section is missing from my data, could this be the cause of the issue? also on geojson.io anything more than 2 rows of coordiantes will not display.

[image] vs my geojson [image]

Comment: It looks like geojson.io always parses the original JSON data and converts it into a FeatureCollection even if there is only one geometry (in this case a LineString).
I think both representations are valid, so I don't think that's the issue.
I noticed in your first screenshot you have a MultiLineString, whereas when I run `ST_ASGEOJSON(ST_MAKELINE(ARRAY_AGG(...)))` it returns just a LineString. Maybe that is one difference?
Does your original GeoJSON validate cleanly in the [GeoJSONLint validator](https://geojsonlint.com)?

Comment: i have tried with a row of single line string as well without any luck, lint validator gives a correct geojson so not sure what is the cause. on a side note is it possible to convert the multilinestring to a singleline and then convert back to geojson? i am new to bigquery and sql and from what i was told it could be done with st_dump but then st_dump cannot be converted to geojson, i need to do a unnest on the st_dump and then convert to geojson